# Image with hyperlink not working after using linear background gradient effect in css

Tags: html, image, css, background-image

I was using a image with hyperlink as below,

```
<div class="image">
    <div class="f_image">
        <a href="1.html"><img src="http://www.portlandmercury.com/binary/e64e/food1-570x300.jpg"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="image-gradient"></div>
</div>
```

From the above html code, my image `1.jpg` works fine with a clickable hyperlink.

I like to add a background gradient effect over that image using `<div class="image-gradient"></div>`. So after executing the gradient effect, the image shows but not as a clickable one. I have tried `z-index`, but image gradient disappears. Could any one help me?

My css code is,

```
.image {
    position: relative;
}

.image-gradient{
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51,51,51,0) 0%, rgba(51,51,51,0.9) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(51,51,51,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(51,51,51,0.9)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51,51,51,0) 0%,rgba(51,51,51,0.9) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51,51,51,0) 0%,rgba(51,51,51,0.9) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51,51,51,0) 0%,rgba(51,51,51,0.9) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(51,51,51,0) 0%,rgba(51,51,51,0.9) 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mxafr) helps you.

HTML

```
<div class="f_image">
<a href="1.html">
   <img src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/sachin_tendulkar-normal.jpg"/>                                   <span class="image-gradient"></span>
   </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.f_image a {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.f_image img {
position: relative;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.image-gradient{
position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
color: #fff;
padding: 1em;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51,51,51,0) 0%, rgba(51,51,51,0.9) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(51,51,51,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(51,51,51,0.9)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51,51,51,0) 0%,rgba(51,51,51,0.9) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51,51,51,0) 0%,rgba(51,51,51,0.9) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(51,51,51,0) 0%,rgba(51,51,51,0.9) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(51,51,51,0) 0%,rgba(51,51,51,0.9) 100%);
}
```

Comment: no bro still the gradient shows only at the top side of the image.. Note that my image size is 570x300.. After i updating your code my image seems to be clickable but the gradient shows only at the top section, not for the full image..

Comment: can you add your image? so I can understand the issue.

Comment: Have you moved .image-gradient inside <a> ?

Comment: Hey Tushar working great thank you so much love you.. without doing anything with my code, i have directly added .image-gradient into <a href=""><img src="1.jpg"/><div class="image-gradient"></div></a>. Now it works fine..

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
  margin-top:-25px;
```

instead of

```
position: absolute;
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Z565B/

Comment: @user3559304, i don't get u. According to my fiddle. The gradient effect is still as background for the image.and the image is clickable.Is this your requirement.? Do you check my fiddle ?

Comment: if you put the live image on that img for eg: 570x300 you could see the image not fully gradient.. only top of the section seems to be gradient.. i think you could understand..